# Docker container of flask app is possible connect to localhost MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask, connection

I’m new to docker.
I have the one flask app was running on my docker container and the application needs to connect to MongoDB for the CRUD action.

but I have some connection problems between the docker and the localhost. The container cannot connect to my localhost MongoDB.

So is a possible flask app from docker container connect to the localhost MongoDB?

My Flask app MongoDB config setup:

```
cilent = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1',27017)
```

My Dockerfile config:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Michael Levan

CMD tail -f /dev/null

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5000

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion, it'll be easy to create mongodb inside the Docker. However you could check [connect docker to local db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database) and [docker to local mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314900/how-to-connect-local-mongo-database-to-docker/52318134).